# Error Log Management in asp.net application in Production Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing asp.net application using log4net to log the errors, however if I want to change the error log format I must change the application code again after publishing into production, 
 My question is which is the best option to change(error log for third party API's) the error log without affecting the production server?

Answer (score 1):

Configuring log4net using config files will let you to change logging without touching code
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial